# Tensorflow cannot decode csv

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I have the following code taken from the book "TensorFlow 1.x Deep Learning Cookbook", where the dataset has been taken from http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Global Parameters
DATA_FILE = 'boston_housing.csv' 
BATCH_SIZE = 10
NUM_FEATURES = 14

# Define function thaat takes the file name and returns
# tensors in batches of size equal to batch_size
def data_generator(filename):
    '''
    Generates Tensors in batches of size BATCH_SIZE.
    Args: String Tensor
    Filename from which data is to be read
    Returns: Tensors
    feature_batch and label_batch
    '''
    # Define the filename that is "f_queue" and "reader"
    f_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename)
    reader  = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)   # Skips the first line
    _, value = reader.read(f_queue)

    # Specify data to use in case of missing data. Decode the csv and select the features we need. For instance
    # We choose RM, PTRATIO, LSTAT.
    record_defaults = [ [0.0] for _ in range(NUM_FEATURES)]
    data = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults = record_defaults)
    features = tf.stack(tf.gather_nd(data, [[5], [10], [12]]))
    label = data[-1]

    # Define parameters to generate batch and use tf.train.shuffle_batch() for randomly
    # shuffling tensors. The function returns the tensors-- feature_batch and label_batch

    # Minimum number of elements in the queue after a dequeue
    min_after_dequeue=10*BATCH_SIZE

    # Maximum number of element in the queue
    capacity = 20 * BATCH_SIZE

    # Shuffle the data to generate BATCH_SIZE sample pairs
    feature_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([features, label], 
                                                         batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                                                         capacity = capacity,
                                                         min_after_dequeue = min_after_dequeue)
    return feature_batch, label_batch


# Function that generate the batches in the session 
def generate_data(feature_batch, label_batch):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # initialize the queue threads
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        for _ in range(5): # generate 5 batches
            features, labels = sess.run([feature_batch, label_batch])
            print(features, 'HI')
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

# Run
if __name__ == '__main__':
    feature_batch, label_batch = data_generator([DATA_FILE])
    generate_data(feature_batch, label_batch)
```

However, when I run this, I obtain the following errors

> INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: , Expect 14 fields but have 1 in record 0
>            [[Node: DecodeCSV_1 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], field_delim=",", na_value="", use_quote_delim=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ReaderReadV2_1:1, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0, DecodeCSV_1/record_defaults_0)]]
>
> OutOfRangeError: RandomShuffleQueue '_41_shuffle_batch_4/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 10, current size 0)
>        [[Node: shuffle_batch_4 = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shuffle_batch_4/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch_4/n)]]

I am very new to tensorflow and the book offers little to no explaination of what is going on.. this is supposed to work on Python 3.5 and Tensorflow 1.3. Can you at least point me in the correct direction?

Comment: It seems tf has been changed since the tutorial was created. Check https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/programmers_guide/reading_data

Comment: That link is also outdated (it's about version 1.0). Check how to read data for the current version (1.5 as of now)

Comment: Also, your code skips one line only (`tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)`), but the file you link to has a lot more header lines. That is probably the source of your error.

Comment: @Manngo Thank you! Would you be able to tell me what's wrong in the code?

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks! To be honest the book doesn't even tell you how to get the data from that url to a csv. I just copied and pasted to be honest.. However, I understand what you mean and I will definitely try!